Why Does Disabling Non-Mandatory Copy Elision Result in Different Behaviors Before and After C++17
I've been experimenting with the following C++ code using different compiler flags and versions, observing differing behaviors in object construction between C++11 and C++17.
I noticed that with the -fno-elide-constructors flag in both C++17 and C++11, NRVO is disabled inside the function f. However, in C++17, the object t1 is created directly at the location of t2, but in C++11, this step wasn't eliminated. I'm wondering why in C++17, despite disabling that flag, this step was still eliminated, considering this is not a case of mandatory copy elision!
Also I checked a lot of sources here and those famous questions and couldn't figure it out why!
Her is also link to the code:
https://godbolt.org/z/PYfejba6M
#include <iostream>

struct Thing
{
    Thing() { std::cout << "Constructor\n"; }

    ~Thing() { std::cout << "Destructor\n"; }

    Thing(const Thing&) { std::cout << "Copy Constructor\n"; }

    Thing& operator=(const Thing&) { std::cout << "Copy Assignment Operator\n"; return *this; }

    Thing(Thing&&) noexcept { std::cout << "Move Constructor\n"; }

    Thing& operator=(Thing&&) noexcept { std::cout << "Move Assignment Operator\n"; return *this; }
};

Thing f()
{
    std::cout << "Entering f()\n"; 
    Thing t1;
    std::cout << "Thing t1 constructed in f()\n"; 
    std::cout << "Preparing to return t1 from f()\n";
    return t1;
}

int main()
{
    std::cout << "Entering main()\n"; 
    [[maybe_unused]] Thing t2 = f();
    std::cout << "t2 object returned and assigned in main()\n";
    std::cout << "Exiting main()\n"; 
}


In Thing t2 = f(), avoiding a copy or move from function return value is in fact mandatory starting from C++17. This line must compile even if you make Thing non-copyable and non-movable (whereas in C++11 it must not compile).

C++17 introduced mandatory RVO that cannot be disabled by -fno-elide-constructors. This flag tunes non mandatory NVRO.

Thank you both for the responses! However, isn't mandatory copy elision applicable when a temporary is returned from a function, where the expression in the return statement has a prvalue category, not an lvalue? Here, t1 is an lvalue as an expression, but if we were to return Thing(), it would be a prvalue and thus subject to mandatory copy elision. I am confused!

I also noticed that the link below doesn’t consider my code above eligible for mandatory copy elision. But you think it is eligible!
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12953127/what-are-copy-elision-and-return-value-optimization?rq=2

The value category of a function call expression is an rvalue unless the function return type is a reference type. What happens inside the function is irrelevant. Consider: the function may have two branches, one doing return 42; and the other int x = 42; return x;. The compile-time behaviour of the function call can't possibly depend on the path it takes at run time.

In other words: there are two copies/moves involved. One is from the expression of the return statement to the return value of the function, the other from the return value to the variable being initialized by the result of the function call. These copies are independent; in principle, none, either or both may be elided. In your example, the elision of the copy from t1 to return value is optional (known as NRVO); the elision of the copy from the return value to t2 is optional in C++11, mandatory in C++17.

@IgorTandetnik Thank you for the explanation, but if you check the code in the link below, then you'll see the compiler throws an error! If the elision of the copy from the return value to t2 is  mandatory in C++17, then why would compiler throw an error?https://godbolt.org/z/4EdWTErff    if i change t1 to Thing(), then code compiles which is a mandatory copy elision.

Again, imagine that there's an intermediary unnamed temporary object that's a return value of the function. Let's call it R. return t; conceptually involves moving from t to R; this is NRVO, optionally elided. Initializing Thing t2 = f() conceptually involves moving from R to t2; starting from C++17, this is always elided. What's failing in your example is the first move. (continued)

While NRVO can be elided, it must still be well-formed when not elided: the compiler checks that the appropriate move or copy constructor is available, even if it ends up not calling that constructor. You don't want the same program to be well-formed on one compiler that performs the optional optimization, and ill-formed on another that does not. In contrast, the mandatory elision doesn't check for the constructor, and in fact is required to work even if no copy/move constructor is available.

@IgorTandetnik Oh! Interesting! That makes sense :) Thank you so much! It has been very very helpful.

@IgorTandetnik also that last comments could have been an answer. I am sure many out there still struggling with such nuances you explained.

@Sam I also noticed that the link below doesn’t consider my code above eligible for mandatory copy elision you had to read up to the end. That question was written in 2012. The answer was updated with C++17 addendum. SO yeah, it's technically a dupe for question  but answer had been changed over time.

So, first off, when you say "in C++17, the object t1 is created directly at the location of t2", you're not describing the behavior of your code correctly. In your own godbolt link, with -std=c++17 -fno-elide-constructors, you'll note it still shows one Move constructor output, and a paired Destructor output. t1 was not created directly at the location of t2. With -std=c++11 -fno-elide-constructors, you get two Move constructor outputs, so C++17 is eliding one of two moves even with the flag, but not both.
The reason is that -fno-elide-constructors disables optional copy-elision. NRVO is optional in both standards, so regardless of C++ standard, it does, in fact, cause a single move to occur when you do return t1; in f, moving from the t1 inside the function to the "staging area" for the return value.
In C++11, this "staging area" is separate from the t2 that is initialized by the function call; the copy-elision from the "staging area" to t2 is non-mandatory (because C++11 lacks mandatory copy-elision) and is disabled by -fno-elide-constructors, so you end up moving twice, once from t1 to staging area, once from staging area to t2.
By contrast, in C++17 and higher, the copy from "staging area" to t2 is a case where copy-elision is mandatory. So while -fno-elide-constructors disables the non-mandatory copy-elision from t1 to the "staging area", the "staging area" itself is required to be t2 itself (because Thing t2 = f(); requires elision), so only one move occurs, directly from t1 to t2.

I like the phrase 'staging area'—great explanations! Thank you! So, I have another question in the link below, let's say copy elision is disabled. Would it be accurate to say that a move is going to happen because it's an implicit move? Like if the compiler can't apply NRVO for some technical reasons, it treats the return of 'coll' as an rvalue and uses move semantics implicitly? https://godbolt.org/z/q7EWj91Ka

@Sam: That's fully answered by Is an object guaranteed to be moved when it is returned?. Short answer: Yes, if move semantics are available, and NRVO isn't available (it's requirements aren't met, or you passed -fno-elide-constructors), it uses move if available, and copy only if move is not available.
